# Maintain $dbh (database handle) across all php files

Tags: pdo

How many ways are there to maintain $dbh (database handle) across all php files,
so that once $dbh created, I can query and update database from any php file and any time, without having to log in.

1) apply $dbh global in every php file ?
2) apply $dbh in the parameter of the called function ? 
3) ?

What other ways are there to, so as  to query and update without ever having to log in again and which is better and simple.

Thanks for your input.

regards
Clement

Comment: Have a look at [Singleton Pattern](http://phpadvocate.com/blog/2011/04/php-using-a-singleton-pattern-with-oop/)

Comment: @davidstrachan, Thanks It helps. Need to digest throughly...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the file that creates $dbh, put

```
global $dbh;
...
$dbh = new DatabaseClass();
$dbh->example_login("user","pass");
...
```

In every file and function that wants to use $dbh, put

```
global $dbh;
...
$result = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM XYZ");
...
```

at the start to mark `$dbh` as global. You could also use a singleton type pattern, although this is considered bad practice in PHP.

Comment: Using global $dbh is a good idea? What other methods are there?

Comment: @user1739825
AFAIK, it is the best thing you can do. I've seen it used extensively for the database handle and some other things in phpBB for example, so it seems like the way to go. As I said, you could always put it in a static variable of a class, kinda like a singleton, but I'd say `global` is the way to go here.

Comment: To AStupidNoob, I could not resolve the problem. Pls refer to [problem] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806637/make-dbh1database-handle-availabel-to-all-php-files).

Comment: I've added a comment there, hopefully it will help you. You should probably accept this answer as correct or answer your own question to show that it doesn't need attention.